# Does smart contract mean coin?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new in blockchain tech. In all videos or documentation, people write tons of things about blockchain and smart contract and I think no one knows exactly what the smart contract means. Because they are not explaining it in an easy way.

When I create a smart contract in `Solidity` and publish in blockchain, am I creating a new coin in blockchain environment?

If so, people could see my coin and invest in it. But I am not creating my smart contract like `Bitcoin` or `Shibacoin`. I want to create it just for storing for example people's `todo app data`.

---

And also **a bonus question:**

I am creating a `todo` app in `Solidity` and publishing it publicly in blockchain. I published my app in `Android Studio` so users can add their `todo` list data.

Data is stored in, I think, every node distributed. Meaning everybody's computer who has blockchain technology stores `todo` app data. If someone closes his/her computer, this means that I can't see some of this data in his/here computer?

The reasoning being that, if people have `todo app data of other people` in their computer, other people's data cannot be hacked?

Comment: Sorry @Coder, but I cannot see the question in your **bonus question** part

Comment: The question is simply not on topic IMHO, as described in [help/on-topic], that might be the reason

Comment: I am writing in topic. smart contracts are coins? When I create a smart contract, am I creating a new coin? Topic is general but I am writing in question more detail.

Comment: @Coder for less technical questions you are maybe better off asking in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If your contract follows a token standard (e.g. [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)), then it effectively represents a token. In other cases, it does not represent any token.

So if you create a ToDo app contract without implementing the token standard functions, then it's not a token.

---

Solidity code effectively runs in EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine), which is part of a distributed system. By design, every node of the network holds the same copy of all data across the system.

Applied to your example: All nodes of the network hold all ToDo notes of all users.

You can distinguish the data on the application level:

```
struct Note {
    uint datetime;
    bool done;
    string note;
}

mapping (address => Note[]) notesPerUser;
```

But if the nature of the data is not meant to be readable by anyone, you might want to use a private EVM network (e.g. Hyperledger) instead of a public one (e.g. Ethereum). Or a completely different architecture (e.g. a centralized database instead of a smart contract).

Comment: first, thank you for your kindly answer. You are saying that all nodes have the same copy data. If one person who uses my todo app, adds tons of todos. For example he/she adds 1000GB data inside the app. Then every nodes are gonna have the 1000GB data? Is there any restriction on it?

Comment: @Coder Your calculation is correct. There's practically no limit on the size of the data collected over time. There's a technical limit of 2^256 storage slots for the whole network combined, each slot for 32 bytes, but that's practically impossible to get any way close to this limit... Every write operation is paid in the form of the network native tokens (ETH in case of Ethereum), which on public networks usually have monetary value. Storing few KB of the contract bytecode on Ethereum usually costs tens of dollars, so storing 1000GB would be insanely expensive for the users.

Comment: I think maybe using cloud aws or azure, can be great idea for it. Because I can use pay as you go method. Etherium takes fee and gas and not stable. Depends on etherium transaction. Fee and Gas value always changes. Depends on wars or elonmusk tweet effects the fee and gas cost.  even to call for a method inside the code. This technology is not usable for these times, I think.